# Twilio incoming call scenario

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Wanted to know if there is a way to implement this use case in Twilio (using taskrouter or other mechanisms),

The scenario is this:

1. A consumer calls into a Twilio number
2. Call flow calls a API that returns 3 Agent phone numbers
3. Consumer needs to be connected to one of 3 agents based on the following logic,

   - Begins calling Agent Phone number 1
   - After  rings/seconds without answer
   - Agent Phone number 2 is dialed
   - BUT the attempt to reach Agent Phone 1 continues
   - Similarly, Agent Phone number 3 is dialed
   - Until the call is answered by either Agent 1,2, or 3

I know the agents can be dialed simultaneously which is not I want.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As far as I know, there is no way to start calls to multiple numbers after a staggered delay as you are suggesting. The two options are to time out the first call and then try the second call, and same for second to third call. Or call each agent simultaneously (which you don't want).